# Smarty (PHP) math issue with rounded results. Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I'm struggling with this issue. In a Prestashop store, I would like to display how much is the saving the client with a discounted product. So I included this if statement in the prices block:

```
{* Savings *}
    {if $product.has_discount}
        {$savings = ($product.regular_price)-($product.unit_price_full)}
        <div class="fs-6 savings-badge">
            <span style='font-size:14px;'>&#127808;</span><span>Ahorra {$savings|string_format:"%.2f"}€</span>
        </div>
    {/if}
```

The problem is the calculus. For example, if the product price was 4.95€ and now it costs 1.50€ the result is equal to 3.00. So the output is wrong (should be 3.45). I think my problem is in math operation in $savings variable.

Does anybody know how can I get a more accurate result? Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3bkj.png)

Comment: Is "the original" `$savings` wrong or `$savings` after you apply `string_format:"%.2f"` (whatever that does)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prestashop or its templating system but don't see anything obviously wrong. If `$savings` is somehow being cast to an int, you'll get 3.00 as a result, but I don't see where that might be happening. If you dump all the involved variables, do they contain what you think they do?

Comment: @brombeer I'm using string_format:"%.2f" to display two decimals. If I remove that part, the result stills incorrect. Seems not to be calculating accurate... I'm updating the post with a screenshot of the result in order to ease more information. Thanks for answering

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for your response. I have checked multiple global variables in case the parameters of the formula weren't correct. However I always have similar results. For example, I tried this >> Instead "regular price" - "discounted price" I tried "regular price" * "total percentage discounted". It is a rounded error and how this math operations shows decimals... I'm stacked by now.